# Newsfeed error - The operation failed because the server could not access the distributed cache

Tags: user-profile, my-site, 2013

I've recently installed SharePoint 2013 RTM and on the newsfeed page the error "The operation failed because the server could not access the distributed cache." with no items are available in the following or everyone tabs.

- Activity feeds and mentions tabs are working as expected.
- User Profile Service is operational and syncing as expected
- Search is operational and indexing as expected
- The farm was installed based on the autospinstaller scripts.
- Don't believe this to be a permissions issue, during testing added accounts to the admin group to verify
- Restarted the Distributed Cache Service
- Confirmed the AppFabric Service is online via get-cache

Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

The full error message and trace logs is as follows.

SharePoint returned the following error: The operation failed because the server could not access the distributed cache. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 55. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem.

From the trace logs there's several messages which are triggered around the same time:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspxHandling
>   an exception. Exception details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault]:
>   Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.. (Fault Detail is equal
>   to
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault)./LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/d71732192b0d4afdad17084e8214321e-1-129962393079894191System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault,
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]],
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Unexpected exception in
>   FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object..     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheService.Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IFeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed(FeedCacheRetrievalEntity
>   fcTargetEntity, FeedCacheRetrievalEntity fcViewingEntity,
>   FeedCacheRetrievalOptions fcRetOptions)       at
>   SyncInvokeGetPublishedFeed(Object , Object[] , Object[] )       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault]:
>   Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.. (Fault Detail is equal
>   to Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault).

SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeed: Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException:

> ServerErrorFetchingConsolidatedFeed : ( Unexpected exception in
>   FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.. ) : Correlation
>   ID:db6ddc9b-8d2e-906e-db86-77e4c9fab08f : Date and Time : 31/10/2012
>   1:40:20 PM       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.PopulateConsolidated(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retOptions, SPMicrofeedContext context)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.Populate(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retrievalOptions, SPMicrofeedContext context)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonGetFeedFor(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retrievalOptions)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonPubFeedGetter(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   feedOptions, MicrofeedPublishedFeedType feedType, Boolean publicView) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.GetPublishedFeed(String
>   feedOwner, SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions feedOptions,
>   MicrofeedPublishedFeedType typeOfPubFeed)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.ISocialFeedManagerProxy.ProxyGetFeed(SPSocialFeedType
>   type, SPSocialFeedOptions options)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<>c_*DisplayClass4b`1.b*_4a()

Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeed:

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException:
>   ServerErrorFetchingConsolidatedFeed : ( Unexpected exception in
>   FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.. ) : Correlation
>   ID:db6ddc9b-8d2e-906e-db86-77e4c9fab08f : Date and Time : 31/10/2012
>   1:40:20 PM       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.PopulateConsolidated(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retOptions, SPMicrofeedContext context)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.Populate(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retrievalOptions, SPMicrofeedContext context)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonGetFeedFor(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   retrievalOptions)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonPubFeedGetter(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions
>   feedOptions, MicrofeedPublishedFeedType feedType, Boolean publicView) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.GetPublishedFeed(String
>   feedOwner, SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions feedOptions,
>   MicrofeedPublishedFeedType typeOfPubFeed)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.ISocialFeedManagerProxy.ProxyGetFeed(SPSocialFeedType
>   type, SPSocialFeedOptions options)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<>c__DisplayClass4b`1.<S2SInvoke>b__4a()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager
>   target, String name, Func`1 func)

Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeed:

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException: The operation failed
>   because the server could not access the distributed cache. Internal
>   type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException.
>   Internal error code: 55.       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.TryTranslateExceptionAndThrow(Exception
>   exception)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager
>   target, String name, Func`1 func)       at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<>c__DisplayClass48`1.b__47()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager
>   target, String name, Func`1 func)

When I removed my personal site, and recreated, the following message appears in the event log.

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID 29a08560-582e-4079-b8ef-04f7e036b989) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>
> Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.IsRepopulationNeeded: Communications with the cache cluster has experienced a delay past the timeout value,please increase the RequestTimeout of the client

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the preview forum, I came across the following post

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mpriem/archive/2012/08/20/sharepoint-2013-preview-newsfeeds-showing-nothing.aspx

The issue was the User Profile Service Application, had not been granted full control for the account that was running the service (i.e. service apps account).

On a side note, this also resolved the issue with the Work Management Service not updating.

Comment: This has been the solution to this issue in many cases for me as well. After provisioning be sure to grant services the account access to the User Profile Service application.